# Spring Boot addObject not working correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am trying to display a string in springboot web page but it,s not working correctly !

controller

```
@Controller
public controller {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView get(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index.html");
        String name = "World";
        model.addObject("name",name);
        return model;
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Hello <span th:text="${name}"></span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

it works like this

[image]

Comment: Can you try to remove .html extension first?

Comment: i did it but it,s still not work !

Comment: Ye, you should add a namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Controller
    public controller {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public ModelAndView get(){
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
            String name = "World";
            model.addObject("name",name);
            return model;
        }
    }
```

Test by removing the .html
Also add `th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"` like below.

```
   <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <h1>Hello th:text="${name}"></h1>
```

Try removing the span or correctly add the content inside the span.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything in java classes and even you don't need to remove the span in the HTML file. Check with the namespace in the HTML. The following is working without any issue with `spring-boot <2.2.9.RELEASE>` and using the `thymeleaf` template engine.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {
  
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView get(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index.html");
        String name = "World";
        model.addObject("name",name);
        return model;
    }
    
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        Hello <span th:text="${name}"></span>
    </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried but it still not work. (works as previous).